# Legend seems not to work with scale_discrete when trying to group by multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the content of a data frame, containing experimental data of a continuous variable `Y` which depends on another continuous variable `X`, and on two categorical variables `groups` and `level`.

```
x=seq(2,7,length.out=5)
sigma=0.25
y1l=1.5*x1+4+rnorm(5,sd=sigma)
y1h=1.5*x1+5+rnorm(5,sd=sigma)
y2l=1.5*x1+7+rnorm(5,sd=sigma)
y2h=1.5*x1+8+rnorm(5,sd=sigma)
y3l=1.5*x1+9+rnorm(5,sd=sigma)
y3h=1.5*x1+10+rnorm(5,sd=sigma)
X=rep(x,6)
Y=c(y1l,y1h,y2l,y2h,y3l,y3h)
groups=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=10)
level=rep(rep(c("low","high"),each=5),times=3)
df=data.frame(groups,level,X,Y)
```

My idea is to use a `geom_point` and a `geom_line` layer, because in the real data frame, the experimental points are extremely noisy, and not always well separated by `groups` and `level`. Thus, adding a `line` layer to the obvious `point` layer to connect points having the same values of `groups` and `level`, makes the plot more readable. In practice I use

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data=df,aes(x=X, y=Y, fill = groups,size=level),
                    shape=21, color=NA) +
         geom_line(data=df,aes(x=X, y=Y, color = groups,linetype=level)) + 
         scale_size_discrete("level", range=c(1,2)) +
         scale_linetype_discrete(name=NULL,labels=NULL,breaks=NULL)
p
```

I get

[image]

It looks nice enough (suggestions for improvement are welcome, though :) The only problem is the `level` legend. Why doesn't it show the small and large circles used for plotting? How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating your plot as follows works:

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data=df,aes(x=X, y=Y, colour = groups, size=level)) +
  geom_line(data=df,aes(x=X, y=Y, color = groups,linetype=level)) + 
  scale_size_discrete("level", range=c(1,2)) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name=NULL,labels=NULL,breaks=NULL)
p
```

[image]

So, what was wrong with your original plot? You used `shape = 21` which is a dot has a border and a filling. The colour of the filling is determined by `fill` and the border by `colour`. But then set `colour = NA` which means that there is no border at all.

Since each point size came with various values for `fill`, the legend for size ignored the fill colour and only used the colour `aesthetic`. You can check that this is true with the following plot, where I also used `shape = 21`, but omitted `colour = NA`:

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data=df,aes(x=X, y=Y, fill = groups, size=level),
                    shape=21) +
  geom_line(data=df,aes(x=X, y=Y, color = groups,linetype=level)) + 
  scale_size_discrete("level", range=c(1,2)) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name=NULL,labels=NULL,breaks=NULL)
p
```

[image]

As you see, the size legend is drawn with empty circles that have a black border. If you set the border colour to `NA`, they will be "drawn" with an invisible border.

The solution is thus to omit `shape = 21`, which will plot points that don't have a border and have their colour determined by `colour`. Now also the size legend is drawn with filled dots, as you probably wanted.